# Vectorised font not filling shape fully [Illustrator]

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector, shapes, fill

RESOLVED: I had problems with the rendering, switching to CPU rendering fixed the display.

---

I can't figure out what's wrong here.

I turned a font into outlines so I can adjust the shape a little more. My problem is that the color-fill of the shape is not filling the shape fully (the fill even extends a little over the edge at some places). This is happening throughout the whole shape. I have this problem even if I draw something new with the pen tool (in the same file).

You can only notice it if you zoom in.

Any ideas on what's happening?

I added a picture of how it looks like:

[image: Image of shape that's only partially filled]

Comment: How did you vectorize it?  Did you auto trace a bitmap, did you turn an existing letter into outlines, was it hand drawn using the Pen Tool, or some other tool? Unfortunately I can't replicate the problem. Please edit your question and provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: Turn to cpu rendering. Looks like  a GPU render glitch

Comment: Sorry, I now added that bit of info to my question. I turned the letters into outlines. But I seem to have the same problem even if I redraw something from scratch with the pen tool. 

I do not have this issue if I open a new file and draw there. The problem re-appears as soon as I copy my shape (font turned into outlines) into the (new) file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree with @joojaa - this could be a GPU rendering glitch. Try clicking *View > Preview on CPU*. If that fixes it, then you almost certainly have a graphics card glitch. You could try updating your graphics card drivers to fix it. Failing that, contact Adobe customer support directly.

Comment: It's really the rendering. Thank you @joojaa & Billy Kerr! I'll have a look at my drivers too. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with your GPU rendering option switch to CPU rendering (View → Preview on CPU)